# SphinxQL Facet returns no more than 1000 results

Tags: php, sphinx, sphinxql

I have an sphinx index and I query via sphinx QL with facets...

This is my sphinx ql query:

```
SELECT ID FROM index_search WHERE MATCH('refrigerator') ORDER BY WEIGHT() DESC LIMIT 0,20
OPTION max_matches=5000
FACET CATEGORY_ID
FACET MANUFACTURER_ID
FACET STORE_ID
FACET VALUE_ID LIMIT 5000;
SELECT MIN(MIN_PRICE), MAX(MIN_PRICE) FROM index_search WHERE MATCH('refrigerator');
SHOW META
```

Now this returns results like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array([id] => 3256)
        ...
            [19] => Array([id] => 3242)

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ... category filters ...
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            ... manufacturer filters ...
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            ... store filters ...
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value_id] => 0
                    [count(*)] => 1146
                )

            ...

            [999] => Array
                (
                    [value_id] => 221820
                    [count(*)] => 1
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [min(min_price)] => 0.000000
                    [max(min_price)] => 0.000000
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Variable_name] => total
                    [Value] => 5000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Variable_name] => total_found
                    [Value] => 5099
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Variable_name] => time
                    [Value] => 0.009
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Variable_name] => keyword[0]
                    [Value] => refriger
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [Variable_name] => docs[0]
                    [Value] => 5099
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [Variable_name] => hits[0]
                    [Value] => 9053
                )

        )

)
```

As you can see that it only shows the first 1000 facet values for the VALUE_ID filter... while I know that it does have many more values for it...

There was a bug reported about this and I found this solution:

http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=14339

And I got the sphinx upgraded to the following version:

```
Sphinx 2.3.1-id64-beta (r4926)
```

but still the same...

How can I even check if my sphinx installation has this bug fixed??

Comment: why posting here? Seems would be more sensible to post on sphinx forum, or the even on the bug report. Where the actual developers more likely to see it.

Comment: I have posted there too... but SO is more responsive then any other forum and all kinds of developers seem to come here... I had a hope that I will get some answers here...